# Why this line hosing up my tableview?   --  cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

Tags: iphone, uitableview, delegates

When I comment out this line in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function:

```
cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

..then all the cell are regenerated every time and not reused... This causes all my tableview cell current values to be perfectly set.  However, my cells need to display old and new values.  Of course, since the cell is always alloc'd, all the historical values are lost.

..When I leave that line in there, and scroll to the bottom of my tableview, values in the cells at the bottom of the table will contain some of the values that belong to cells at the top...  I've got something mixed up.

In short, I have a `UITableView` made up of custom `UITableViewCell`s.  The custom cells have the following:

- an `UIStepper` control
- an `id delegate` to store the calling `tableView` so I can run methods in the `tableView`.
- properties that allow each cell to store their section and row in the tableview

Problem statement:
When I load up the `tableview` and the user taps the `UIStepper` control in a cell, it calls a delegate function `doit:`, back in the `tableView` implementation.  In that function, the custom cell's section and row properties are working great and they point perfectly to the right section and row in the datasource (and `tableView`),  but the `stepper.value` is set "somehow" to the `stepper.value` from another cell in the table.

Also, I only really notice this anomaly when I scroll significant distances in the table...i.e. from top to bottom.  The bottom cell's `stepper.value` will be that of a cell that was near the top of the table.  So I think I am running into a complication stemming from the way cells are cached, etc...

I've included code from the customCell class as well as from the parent TableView.

Does anyone see the error in my ways?   Many thanks.

Here is the `customTableViewCell` header file.

Back in the actual TableView, where i instantiate the custom cells, I call the custom cell's `setDelegate:` method, (shown below), in order to be able to understand which cell in the table was clicked.

The "star" of the show is the UIStepper control that allows the user to "up" or "down" the
score value, which is displayed on the cell as well.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tvcCustomCellWithSetter : UITableViewCell {
    id delegate;
    NSNumber * row;
    NSNumber * section;
    int      originalValueIsSet; }

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *score; @property
(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *catAndWeight; @property
(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *orgValueText; @property
(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *orgValueValue; @property
(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIStepper *theStepper; @property
(nonatomic, assign) id delegate; @property (nonatomic, assign)
NSNumber *row; @property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *section;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int originalValueIsSet;

- (IBAction) bumpTheScore;
- (id)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate;

@end
```

Here is the important part of the customTableViewCell .m file:

```
//
// here is my IBACTION function associated with a touch event on the UISetter control
//
-(void) bumpTheScore {

    [self.delegate doit:self];

}


- (id)delegate {
    return delegate;
}

// 
// this function is called when the cell is alloc'd over in the Tableview controller.
// it allows this custom cell to maintain a reference to the 
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {
    delegate = newDelegate;
}
```

Here is the TableView that houses the customViewCell objects.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    tvcCustomCellWithSetter *cell = nil;

    cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[tvcCustomCellWithSetter class]]) {
                cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }


    } 

    // since the cell is a custom cell and it lives in a new class file, when events 
    // occur from toys in that cell (i.e. sliders, stepper, etc), the events go to that
    // class file.  I want those events to go to the simgrades class and run a reactive
    // function in there.  this is how you do that.   see the two functions in the 
    // custom class that work with this line.
    [cell setDelegate:self];

    // similarly, save the current section and row into the custom cell itself
    // so that later, when the stepper is clicked on one of the cells, we'll be able
    // to know the location in the datasource that is being addressed by the user.
    [cell setRow: [NSNumber numberWithInt: indexPath.row]];
    [cell setSection: [NSNumber numberWithInt: indexPath.section]];      

    // Set up the cell...
    [self.tableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:NO];
    SimCat *tmpCat = [simCatalog objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
    SimGrade *tmpGrd = [[tmpCat simGrades] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    float averageScore, _score, _total;
    _score = [tmpGrd.scoreValue floatValue];
    _total = [tmpGrd.scorePossible floatValue];
    averageScore = (_score / _total) * 100;

    // Configure the cell...  Category name and description
    if (tmpGrd.isSimGrade) {
        cell.score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SimGrade: %2.2f%% - (%@ of %@)", averageScore, [tmpGrd.scoreValue stringValue] , [tmpGrd.scorePossible stringValue]];
        //for simulation grades, null out the orgValue labels.
        cell.orgValueValue.text = [NSString stringWithString: @""];
        cell.orgValueText.text = [NSString stringWithString: @""];
    } else {
        cell.score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Actual: %2.2f%% - (%@ of %@)", averageScore, [tmpGrd.scoreValue stringValue] , [tmpGrd.scorePossible stringValue]];
        //set the orig value label and turn on the boolean that shows that you've set this already.
        if (! cell.originalValueIsSet ) {
            cell.orgValueValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tmpGrd.scoreValue stringValue]];
            cell.orgValueText.text = [NSString stringWithString: @"Original Value:"];
            cell.originalValueIsSet = true;
        }
    }

    cell.catAndWeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category: %@, Wt: %d", tmpCat.catName, [[tmpCat catWeight] intValue]];

    [cell.theStepper setValue:[tmpGrd.scoreValue floatValue]];
    [cell.theStepper setMaximumValue:[tmpGrd.scorePossible floatValue]];
    [cell.theStepper setMinimumValue:0];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is where I have the problem.  See the problem description in the code below.

```
- (void) doit: (id) sender {

    NSLog(@"it worked - i got back inside the tableview that houses the custom cells");
    NSLog(@"the user touched the UISetter control on a cell in section: %d", [[(tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)sender section] intValue]);
    NSLog(@"and that cell was in row: %d of that section", [[(tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)sender row] intValue]);

    // find the right section and row in the tableview's data source
    // point to the section indicated by the "section" passed in from the custom cell.
    SimCat *cat = [simCatalog objectAtIndex:[[(tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)sender section] intValue] ];

    // now point at the array item that corresponds to the "row" passed in from the custom cell
    SimGrade *grade = [[cat simGrades] objectAtIndex:[[(tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)sender row] intValue]];

    // now that we are pointing at the right array item in the tableview's datasource, update it's value to that of the UIStepper
    // control's value.
    // THE PROBLEM OCCURS IN THE FOLLOWING LINES.  The before value that is printed out is perfect.  So I know I am able to 
    // reference the correct value in the datasource that the user has just incremented or decremented with the UIStepper
    // control.  The "theStepper.value" should contain a number that is one more or one less than the previous value...
    // HOWEVER, the value stored in theStepper.value is actually a value from one of the other cells in the table.
    // I'm thinking that this has to do with the way the table cells are cached.  I usually see this error when I scroll to the
    // bottom of the tableview.  

    NSLog(@"before: %f", [[grade scoreValue] floatValue]);
    grade.scoreValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [[(tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)sender theStepper] value]];
    NSLog(@"after: %f", [[grade scoreValue] floatValue]);

    // you have changed some values in the Tableview's datasource so you should repaint the view.
    [self loadHTMLHeader];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];

    return;
}
```

Comment: You marked all your properties as `assign` - `@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UILabel *score;`. More correct approach is to mark it as `retain`.

Comment: Thanks, beryllium.  But I changed all to 'retain' and no joy.  Here is an update to the problem statement.  When I comment out the line below in my TableView, the cells are not reused and the UIStepper.value is right.  But this breaks my ability to persist the cell's original "score" value, since each cell is regenerated every time.   (I show old and new values in the cells).  Here is the line I refer to above:     cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by beating my head against the wall and subclassing the UIStepper class in order to add a row and section property that enabled me to determine which tableview cell it was that was presenting the control when it was clicked.  I also used a "setTarget" method, placed on each cell during the cellforrowatindexpath() method, it would call a function in my tableview class whenever the value changed on the UIStepper.  Over in that function, I was able to exploit the row and section values from the customStepper in order to pinpoint the row in the table and hence the datasource that needed to be updated.

Whew.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `theStepper` values from carrying over, you need to explicitly set them to a default value if your `dequeueReusableCell..` method returns a cell.

So:

```
cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[tvcCustomCellWithSetter class]]) {
            cell = (tvcCustomCellWithSetter *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    cell.theStepper.value = 0;
    cell.theStepper.maximumValue = 1;
    // cell.theStepper.minimumValue = 0; this should already be set properly
}
```

Once you do this, then you can do further debugging to see if your values are not being set properly (if the value is zero when it should be otherwise, you know it's failing to set the proper value for that particular cell, and then place breakpoints in the code and look at the variable values etc).

*EDIT:* I'll be more specific. From debugging, you WILL see as you step through the code that:

- The stepper values are explicitly set to default values prior to setting the correct value, or
- The values are not explicitly set to default (which means your value reset code doesn't work).

And then:

- The stepper value is set to the right value for the current cell, or
- The stepper value is set to a DIFFERENT value than what was expected (in which case you then need to trace the code at the point where it's setting that value and see what the indexes are and which value it ends up picking etc), OR
- The stepper value was not altered at all from its default (which means that the code to set is falling over or there is an unusual case where you end up with a `nil`, `0` or simply no code executed to set a value, and you need to trace and see where the code goes to get to that stage).

This should be your standard debugging procedure.

Comment: Thanks, darvidsOn, will set that and try some break point debugging.  Back at you in :20m.

Comment: Nope, no joy.  I'm really stuck on this one.  Any other suggestions?